# sftp using proxy issue: ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to UNKNOWN port 65535: Connection corrupted

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy, ftp, sftp

Our automated script connects to third party server (using proxy), to get some files over sftp.
It usually works fine. On a random day, I got below error. What could be the root cause.?

`sftp> mget TR_ACK*.txt
Bad packet length 1131376238.
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to UNKNOWN port 65535: Connection corrupted
Connection closed`

Edit: FYI- Our script runs every 5min. The above issue occured at 12:05 min. The run at 12:00 min was also failed as the server was down at 12:00. The server was just up just before the time was 12:05 minutes.

Comment: This might work for you: https://askubuntu.com/a/142430/425040